# Basic question about normality assumption for error terms in SLR

Tags: regression, self-study, normality-assumption

I had this question from a quiz in my stats class:

Which of the following is NOT a correct way to specify the assumptions needed for inference about the parameters of a Simple Linear Regression Model?

A. The experimental units are randomly selected, the responses are Normally distributed, and there is a constant variance of the points around the line.

B. The responses are random and Normally distributed with a mean of zero and constant variance.

C. The errors are independent and normally distributed with a mean of zero and constant variance.

D. $ε \sim \mbox{iid } N(0, σ)$

Now, of course the correct response my professor was looking for was B. But, I was under the impression that the error terms do not have to be normally distributed thus D should also be a correct answer?

Comment: Adding tag "self-study" so you can get the maximal benefit of understanding from answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange question!

What we call "ordinary least squares" (OLS) your prof calls "SLR" which is fine. Just like you learned about the reasonableness of the CLT when making inference on a sample proportion when $n$ is reasonably large (>30 is often quoted), regression models have a central limit theorem too. When $n$ is big, we can ignore the exact distribution of the residual. But if $n$ is small, regression is used as an *exact* procedure, and we are making *finite sample* inference (don't confuse this with "finite population"). As an early student, this is too subtle and can be confusing.

The main point is this: **choice B is the wrongest choice** - you already know this, but here's why; **we don't require the *response* to be normally distributed, it's the *error term* that has a normal distribution**. They definitely don't need a zero mean, and any constant variance is a consequence of the *error* term having constant variance - or homoscedasticity as we call it.

Recall $Y = a + bX + e$. If $X$ and $e$ are normally distributed, it just so happens that their sum will be too. But if $X$ is sampled according to something different, I don't care what $Y$ looks like, $e$ needs to be normal.

Comment: I’m still a bit confused, so is D NOT a correct answer because we do not know the sample size of the regression thus the error terms need the assumption of being normally distributed?

Comment: @bernresearch the distribution of the response is the distribution of the error plus the fixed component. If x is sampled according to 0, 1, 2,... And e is normal, y will NOT be normal, but we do not require y to be normal. It is e that must be normal.

Comment: does that not contradict Gauss-Markov theorem?